# LINQ aggregate sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm dynamically building up a query starting with this:

```
var items = db.Items;
```

...

```
case "4":
items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Ratings.Average(t => t.score)).ThenBy(x => x.title);
```

The problem is that some items don't have any data in the ratings table yet, so I believe it's trying to average over data that doesn't exist. Using `DefaultOrEmpty()` at the end doesn't seem to have any effect. Any suggestions on how I would fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   items = items.Where(x=>x.Ratings.Any()).
           OrderBy(x => x.Ratings.Average(t => t.score)).
           ThenBy(x => x.title);
```

Try that.

Comment: I literally just tried that before checking here. I'll accept your answer in 5min when it allows me to.

Comment: Nick and AD.Net are the same person! /ReputationConspiracyTheory

Comment: I've never been to Canada though.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using this form:

```
var effectiveFloor = 
   policies
   .Where(p => p.PricingStrategy == PricingStrategy.EstablishFloor)
   .Max(p => p.Amount);
```

Then the solution is:

```
var effectiveFloor = 
    policies
    .Where(p => p.PricingStrategy == PricingStrategy.EstablishFloor)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    .Max(p => p==null ? 0 : p.Amount);
```

Found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2011/02/15/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements.aspx)